# React-pdf with Next.JS

Tags: pdf, webpack, next.js, react-pdf

I'm trying to use React-pdf with Next.JS to display a pdf on my website.

However, I'm getting the following error when adding it to my website:

`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`

I found several questions and issues about this already, but still can't make it work.

My next.config.js and therefore my webpack config:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require("node:path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.join(
              path.dirname(require.resolve("pdfjs-dist/package.json")),
              "cmaps"
            ),
            to: "cmaps/",
          },
        ],
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

In my layout.tsx I added the PDF.JS worker:

```
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
  "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js",
  import.meta.url
).toString();

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And my component to display the pdf looks like this:

```
"use client";
import { Document } from "react-pdf";

export default function Menu() {
  return menuUrl ? (
    <Document
      file={"https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html"}
      options={{
        cMapUrl: "cmaps/",
        cMapPacked: true,
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
}
```

And my import looks like this:

```
const Menu = dynamic(import("./menu"), { ssr: false });
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!